# I want the image loader to be fired during pageload when i redirect to a page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, image-loading

I have a .net web application in C#
I am using image loader in my application, all is fine, the image loader is working in postback !!
But i have a requirment where i want to fire the image loader in the following case:
I have a customer creation page 
When the customer fill all details and click on submit button
I am internally handling the page redirection through  javascript when user has been successfully registerted, i show a alert message of customer creation and when user clcik on ok of alert its redirected to another page:

```
function confirmCustomerCreation(strCustomerID) {
    alert('Customer ID ' + strCustomerID + ' created successfully.');
    window.location.href = '/SitePages/AgentAction.aspx'; //siteUrl;
    //window.location.href = '/_layouts/TATA_AIG_Portal/Quote/CalculatePremium_PrivateCar_QuickQuote.aspx'; //siteUrl;

}
```

In this case i found the image loader is not working
can any one suggest how to fire image loader in this case
I am using update panel and its related css :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1"
        DynamicLayout="true">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            <div id="blur">
            </div>
            <div id="dvDummy">
            </div>
            <div class="dvLoading" id="loading">
                <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl="/_layouts/IMAGES/images1/LoadingWheel.gif"
                    Height="50px" Width="50px" />
                Loading...
            </div>
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
```